# Submit form by unchecking a checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, form-submit

I submit a form by checking a checkbox like this:

```
<input type=checkbox name=catIds[] id=cat".$row['id']." value=".$row['id']."  onclick='if(this.checked) this.form.submit();' checked>
```

But now I need to submit also the form by setting the box unchecked.
Is this possible?

Thank you.

Comment: define a JS function outside

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking a checkbox with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/checking-a-checkbox-with-jquery)

Comment: Can't you just remove: if(this.checked) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> onclick='if(this.checked) this.form.submit();'
> ```

Just remove the test to see if the checkbox is checked

```
onclick='this.form.submit();'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just on click submit form

```
<input type=checkbox name=catIds[] id=cat".$row['id']." value=".$row['id']."  onclick='this.form.submit();' checked>
```